# pytest parametrized fixture with inheritance - child class has no attributes

Tags: python, inheritance, pytest

I have encountered a strange behavior with a pytest parametrized fixture which I cannot understand.

Given this sample.py :

```
import pytest
import requests
import conftest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('handler_class', [conftest.Child])
def test_simple(my_fixture):
    try:
        requests.get("http://localhost:8000")
    except:
        pass
```

And the following conftest.py in the same directory :

```
class Base(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        super().__init__(request, client_address, server)
        self.value = 0

    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.value)   # AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'value'
        self.send_error(500)

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        super().__init__(request, client_address, server)
        self.value = 1

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(handler_class):
    handler = handler_class
    httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(('', 8000), handler)
    http_thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
    http_thread.start()
    yield
    httpd.shutdown()
```

If you run

> pytest -s sample.py

There is an exception, "AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'value'" Why ? both classes Base and Child have a value attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that the line `print(self.value)` is reached before the line `self.value = 0` in other thread, that's why such error occures. You need to refactor your code something like this:

```
class Base(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server, value=0):
        self.value = value
        super().__init__(request, client_address, server)

    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.value)  # 1 when doing pytest -s sample.py
        self.send_error(500)

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        super().__init__(request, client_address, server, value=1)
```

Comment: This does indeed seem to fix the issue. Interesting that an object can be used without being fully "constructed".

Comment: object if fully constructed after execution of `__new__`, so it can be (theoretically) used before completion of `__init__`